# How do I encrypt my drive during installation?

Tags: encryption, ubiquity

How do I encrypt my drive on ubuntu? I was told that during the installation there would be an option to encrypt my drive, this was never offered.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to encrypt your drive, just your home folder. It would have been in the same place as when you set the password.

[image]